# Command syntax question - ImageDocumentClose

Tags: syntax, dm-script

Try to use the code to close file without saving

```
ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, Boolean saving )
```

but have no idea what I should exactly put for the "Boolean saving".

I tried

```
ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, false )

ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, 5>6)

ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, 0)

ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, 1)
```

all are not working.

Comment: All except the 'false' are valid values for `Boolean`. Your mistake is the first parameter. You just use an ImageDocument without the type declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly there.

> When the *signature* of a method is given in the results window or documentation like:
>
> ```
> void ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument imgDoc, Boolean saving )
> ```
>
> Then it specifies the *type* of each parameter (here `ImageDocument` and `Boolean`) as well as the  *type* of the return value (here `void`, i.e. no return value). The *name* of the parameters is only for additional guidance and not important. In fact, you might come acroess *signatures* given only as:
>
> ```
> void ImageDocumentClose( ImageDocument, Boolean )
> ```

A valid example of using the command is:

```
image img := GetFrontImage()
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentClose( 0 )
```

or equivalent:

```
imageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
ImageDocumentClose( doc, 0 )
```

As always with DM-scripting, you can put the first parameter of a method *in front* of the command with a `.`, but you don't have to.

It is easier to read, though. In particular when many commands are nested vs. them being pipelined.